# Upper Hessenberg + hermitian = tridiagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Are all matrices that both are upper hessenberg and hermitian also tridiagonal?

I want to create some baby examples in python, but I struggle a bit with coming up with 3x3 matrices and 4x4 matrices that are both hessenberg and hermitian and check if my "conjecture" holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Upper Hessenberg means everything below the first subdiagonal is $0$
2. Hermitian means every element on the $i$-th superdiagonal is equal to the complex conjugate of an element on the $i$-th subdiagonal

So, take any element no on the central three diagonals. If that element is below the diagonal, it is on the $k$-th subdiagonal for some $k\geq 2$, and therefore, is $0$ because of point 1 above.

If that element is above the diagonal, it is on the $k$-th superdiagonal. That means it is equal to the conjugate of some element on the $k$-th subdiagonal. Since that element is $0$, the original element is the conjugate of $0$, which is still $0$.

---

Or, for a fully formal proof:

Let the matrix element be denoted as $a_{ij}$.

Remember that:

- A matrix is upper hessenber if and only if, for all $i,j$ such that $i\geq j+2$, we have $a_{ij}=0$.
- If a matrix is hermitian, then $a_{ji} = \overline{a_{ij}}$ where $\overline z$ is the complex conjugate of $z$.

Let $i,j$ be such that $a_{ij}$ is not on the central three diagonals. This means that either $i\geq j+2$ or $i\leq j-1$.

1. If $i\geq j+1$, then, because $A$ is upper Hessenberg, we have $a_ij=0$.
2. If $i\leq j-1$, then, because $A$ is Hermitian, we have $a_{ij}=\overline{a_{ji}}$. But, because $j\geq i+1$ (this follows directly from $i\leq j-1$), we know that $a_{ji}=0$, therefore, $a_{ij}=\overline{a_{ji}}=\overline 0 = 0$.